# How to select a paragraph other than the 1st to be the post's excerpt?

Tags: plugins, post-meta, excerpt, description

My WordPress website has 3 paragraphs and one featured image in a post. How do I make the last or last before para to be the post description??
Are there any plugins to do that? Am already using All in one Seo pack. But it doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress using the Gutenberg Block Editor, in the control panel to the right, you have an excerpt box:
[image: Gutenberg Block Editor Excerpt]

In the Classic Editor you have a metabox under the main post content area:
[image: Classic Editor Excerpt]

If you don't see it there, go to the top of your screen, on the right under the WP Admin Bar, click "Screen Options" and make sure the "Excerpt" option is clicked.
[image: Screen Options]

Comment: I have around 3000 posts, editing each post is not feasible., are there any WordPress functions or possible using a plugin?

Comment: That’s a lot, didn’t realize.  Could have included that info in the question though.  I suspect you could run a one time script that would search the post content for the second <p> tag then write that into the custom post excerpt meta.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. am somewhat new to the forum, are there any plugins to do that? .,

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... ...I think what you'd need is a custom written script that would automatically search through the 3000+ existing posts, extract the 1st paragraph, add it as the post excerpt and then moving forward you'd do it manually.